# More efficient ajax & php interaction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm trying to find more efficient ways to build my site.
I'm currently using an ajax $.post in a setInterval() function to reload the content.

Something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#data").load("data.php");

   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#data").load('data.php');
   }, 1000);

 });
```

But this is too heavy with a lot of users online.
I would like something like this: https://yobit.net/en/dice/

I have no idea how it is made, and what language they used for it.
I would be glad if someone help me discover what is this or point me to an language or method to do something like it.

Sorry for my bad english, not first language.

Thank you :)

Comment: You might look into WebSockets, which allow the *server* to communicate what it needs to to the client.

Comment: I think they use watch.js. If you use jquery ajax function will consume more server bandwidth...

Comment: You can two other way to implement this first webSocket and second one EventSource but  webSocket is batter way fot this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to know about websocket.

You can use websocket by [workerman](https://github.com/walkor/workerman/) or [swoole](https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src).

If you think websoket is inconvenient, ajax long polling also can help you.